# SQL Server LocalDB: after detach and re-attach database to same computer(machine, same path), cannot backup database

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup, localdb, detach

My development environment is C#, SQL Server 2014 LocalDB, SQL Server 2012 Express, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

When users of my application need to move their localDB (`.mdf`) file to another place, another computer (LocalDB server), detaching from computer A and attaching to computer B and then, we can run BACKUP database command successfully.

However, in case users mistakenly detached or users changed their mind to use continuously in computer A, my application has to be able to re-attach the detached LocalDB database file (`.mdf`) to the same computer (same LocalDB server).

When I run `BACKUP DATABASE` command after my application re-attached the database file to same computer successfully, error message shows as,

> Unable to open physical file, The process cannot access the dbfile because the dbfile is in use by another process
>
> BACKUP DATABASE terminated abnormally

So, I entered Microsoft Server Management Studio and can see 2 dbfile with specific name as first is `greendb.mdf` (only name), second is `c:\users\kay\appdata\greendb.mdf` (with full path).

I think the `c:\users\kay\appdata\greendb.mdf` (with full path) is created when the database is detached. And when I click it through security-login-kay-user mapping, unlike other databases show their permissions inside, the detached database with full path doesn't show their permissions and show error message like,

> Unable to cast 'System.DBNull' object to 'System.String' (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

It seems Microsoft LocalDB Server still recognizes the detached database with full path and is confused with newly attached database (only name without full path).

Any excellent ideas will be highly appreciated !

Thank you so much !

Comment: Today, I've found a point that if I detach the localdb and attach continuously in the same Window(for login) of WPF, Backup database in next Window(main window of my application) is successfully done.

However, I assume that if I close the window or close(exit) application after detaching the localdb database, it seems localdb Server create ghost(not official one) localdb with full pathname to do some assigned extra jobs with the ghost(not official one) localdb file, because there's no localdb file officially on the Server.

Comment: I've tested now and confirm 100 % for sure if I detach and attach continuously in same Window of WPF, the ghost localdb is not created and I can see the Backup database command is successfully done.

Do we need to do some additional work to clean completely the name on localdb Sever? Is there some essential option(parameter) needed in the command of detach and Create database For Attach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In detaching localDB,

we have to run  ALTER DATABASE ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE command first to terminate all the incomplete transactions.

Just to explain easily, Before we close a Restaurant, we have to announce to the customers in the Restaurant, 'This Restaurant will be closed very soon, please complete your eating and get outside before closing of Restaurant'

If you're needed to re-attach the localDB to same computer(same localDB Server),

Some activities like these have to be avoided to prevent the ghost(bug?).

1) Trial to open the localDB in code programmatically

2) It seems counting with the name of detached localDB also reminds the existence of localDB to the localDB Server.(SELECT COUNT dbname command in master database)

Strange thing which has to be fixed as a bug is,

if we detach a localDB from master DB, I think it has to be not able to open the detached localDB in code programmatically. However, code like SqlConnection.Open(); runs and pass by without any exception(error) and immediately the fullpath ghost is created.

It seems the name of detached localDB is deleted on master DB but the Server connects the detached localDB through the physical path in the provided connectionstring.

And to decide some localDB is needed to attached or to check it's detached or not, I've developed my own solution(simple code) to do this.

Hope my experience helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I worked a lot using attach and detach operation and finally I figured out that the best practice for us as a developers is working with scripts.

So, if you want to (detach) your db to re (attach) again either with a new name or the same name. I suggest you to generate scripts for your database and script it again.

if you run the script directly you will get an error because you have to delete the old data (the old / new have the same name) and script by default is using the db name which is written in the first line, sure you can remove this line and use the new database you want to use.

- for scripting database including data, make sure to set preference from the wizard (Advanced settings => schema only / data only / schema and data.) choose schema and data

By default the choice is schema only.
choose a destination for your sql file, after running the script and deleting the old data. your backing up process should go with no problems.

Comment: oh..many thanks for your answer. I'm trying to find with your thankful keywords but a bit difficult to find for the time being. I cannot use Wizard but have to make it programmatically from users' side. How can I delete the old data and the first line including db name? And How can I  set preference as Schema and Data ? Internet doesn't seem to have informations on this..Can you please share your valuable experiences and knowledges with some simple code example ? I've been fighting so difficult with this problem for almost 1 month. Thank you so much !